# C# Webbrowser fill in login page programmatically

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webbrowser-control

I have a login form I wanna fill programmatically in C#
I have a webbrowser and I did it this way, but it doesn't fill the form.

```
<div>
    <label class="control-label" for="Login">Login</label>
    <input class="input-sm form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Login field is required." id="Login" name="Login" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div>
    <label class="control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
    <input class="input-sm form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" value="">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Valider" id="CmdValider">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Quitter" onclick="javascript:window.close();">
</div>
```

How I tried to fill them

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Login").SetAttribute("Login", "myLogin");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Password").SetAttribute("Password", "myPassword");
```

I'm only able to click on the login button, which works but is useless until I find how to fill the login and password

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("CmdValider").InvokeMember("click");
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both queries, you should be doing

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("elementid").SetAttribute("value", "something");
```

The only difference is that in `SetAttribute` I'm passing the first argument as `"value"` instead of something else.

Comment: oh so I got wrong in the way of using setattribute. Thanks, I'm gonna try that.

Comment: @Alfakyn1 great! If it worked, kindly select this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I will, I can't test it before tomorrow though. But that's probably it.